# Air Tag not showing on "Find My" on my Mac

Tags: find-my, airtag

I just bought an AirTag to be able to track my bike in case it gets stolen. Thing is, I have an iPad Pro, an MacBook Pro, but no iPhone.

I added the AirTag with my iPad which worked great. The tag is now showing in my "Find My" app as supposed to under "Items".

Anyhow, when opening the "Find My" app on my MacBook pro, I don't get the AirTag, or any other items in the "items" list.

- MacBook Pro is from 2017, it runs Monterey 12.3.1
- iPad Pro is a model "MLQ62FD/A" running iOS 15.2.1
- Both devices are logged in with the same AppleID
- Location sharing in the settings is set to "on" on both devices
- "Find My" is "on" on both devices in iCloud settings

Specifically on my MacBook Pro:

- In "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" -> "Location Services", "Find My" is enabled
- In "System Preferences" -> "Apple ID" -> "iCloud", "Find My" in enabled

[image]
[image]

How do I fix this so that the AirTag is showing up in the Find My app on my MacBook pro?

Comment: Did you get it working? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: I did, but through endless trial and error. Just eventually, the tag showed up. Can't pinpoint what the exact solution was/is :(

Comment: Thing is, I bough two more AirTags now and I'm right back where the problems started

Comment: Aaaand I got it working. Still no idea what it was. Restarted multiple times,nremoved/re-added the airtags multiple times, switched on and off location services. At some point, they simply started showing up. Sorry for bot being able to provide a good and reliable solution

Comment: Yep, got it also working, no clue what did the job, but same procedure: Re-added, restarted mac, made updates - and later the next day they just showed up.

Answer (score 0):

You may need an iOS device to get out of this situation. Here is the playbook:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210973

If you get to the bottom of the page, and still can’t make progress,  are note of your macOS and iOS versions and use the contact us link at the booth, of that page to get Apple support to check out your AppleID.

Comment: I did that and called Apple. They had me log in, log out, reset etc etc etc and in the end, noone was the wiser.